# Subset column values that relate to max 2 unique other values in other column

Tags: r, duplicates, extract

```
PRODUCT           PCODE           X1          X2
A                 123             1           3           
B                 123             3           5           
A                 456             4           7           
A                 789             5           8           
B                 345             9           1           
C                 012             74          2           
D                 472             76          2           
B                 567             2           9           
E                 123             4           5           
D                 263             2           4           
D                 263             2           7
```

Dataframe name = testset

Hi, I have the following dataset below. What I would like to do is subset Values from PRODUCT column that only have <=2 unique values in PCODE. Thus, the endresult would be:

```
PRODUCT
C
D
E
```

As C only has one unique value (012), D two (472, 263) and E one (123). If you could help me dat would be great. I tried different things with the dplyr, but I could not figure out how it works..

Kind regards, Diederik

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(PRODUCT) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(PCODE) <= 2)
```

To get just the unique products in that result, as in your end result, add `%>% distinct(PRODUCT)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should help you in this matter

```
df2 <- df1[-which(duplicated(df1$PCODE)),]
df3 <- aggregate(df2,list(df2$PRODUCT),FUN = length)
df3 <- df3[which(df3$PRODUCT <3),]
result <- df3[1]
```